# Unable to split strings, and confusing ";" requirements

Tags: c#, split

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace DataAnalysis
{
class Data
{
    public int InTime;
    public string InLocation;
    public bool Direction;
    public int LOS_F;

    // create a Data object from a CSV format string.
    static Data FromString(string line)
    {
        var fields = line.split(",");
        return new Data
        {
            InTime = TimeSpan.Parse(fields[3]),
            InLocation = fields[5],
            Direction = fields[5][0], // to get the direction E/N/S/W
            LOS_F = float.Parse(fields[16])
        };
    }
}

class Program
{
    string[] directions = new string[] { "E", "N", "S", "W" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Siva-Admin\Desktop\5.5 Capacity Models\";
        //         ^--- No need to escape the backslashes

        var subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        // The subdirs variable contains the FULL paths

        foreach (string subdir in subdirs)
        {
            List<List<float>> allAvgs = new List<List<float>>();

            using (StreamWriter compiled = new StreamWriter(
                   Path.Combine(subdir, "compiledresults.csv")))
            {
                compiled.Write("heading,EastAvg,NorthAvg,SouthAvg,WestAvg");

                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    List<Data> info = new List<Data>();
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
                           Path.Combine(subdir, "results" + i.ToString() + @"\JourneyTimes.csv")))
                    {
                        // Read the header line first!
                        string line = reader.ReadLine();

                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            info.Add(Data.FromString(line));
                    }

                    List<float> avgs = new List<float>();

                    for (string dir in directions)
                    {
                        List<Data> perDirection = info.Where(d => d.Direction = dir) as List<Data>;
                        float sum = perDirection.Sum(d => d.LOS_F);
                        float average = sum / perDirection.Count();
                        avgs.Add(average);
                    }

                    allAvgs.Add(avgs);

                    compiled.Write("results" + i.ToString() + "," + string.Join(",", avgs) + "\n");
                }

                compiled.Write("scenario_average");

                for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
                {
                    compiled.Write("," + allAvgs.Sum(d => d[0]) / allAvgs.Count());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get the following errors:

```
Error 1; expected(Line 67, "for (string dir in directions)" )
Error 2; expected(LINE 67, "                            " )     
Error 3 'string' does not contain a definition for 'split' and no extension method 'split' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (LINE 20, var fields = line.split (","); )
```

I do not understand the need for the `;` as these are arguments being passed are they not? I also do not understand why I cannot split a string.

Comment: use `line.split(',');` instead

Comment: Produces the same error! String does not contain a definition...

Comment: Public method names in the standard library **always** start with a capital letter, so it's `Split`.

Comment: Ah, I got tunnel vision after looking at it for so long, that solved that problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Error 1 and 2:** Your for loop should be a foreach loop:

```
foreach (string dir in directions)
```

**Error 3:** the S in split should be upper case:

```
var fields = line.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 5):

`for (string dir in directions)` should be `foreach (string dir in directions)`

EDIT to add:

Addtionally, here:

```
List<Data> perDirection = info.Where(d => d.Direction = dir) as List<Data>;
```

You seem to be making an assignment instead of a equality check, i.e

`d.Direction = dir` should be `d.Direction == dir`

However, it still won't work since you are comparing a string to a bool.

Comment: I'm skeptical that `as List<Data>` will work at the end of the Where method.  It would probably be easier to just add .ToList() at the end instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `line.split(",")` with `line.Split(',')` (note the uppercase `S`).
(also replace `for` with `foreach` in line 67 as others have pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

Error1 & Error2 use foreach instead of for;

Erorr3 it's Split instead of split.