# Why does String.Split() not allow a single string as a parameter

Tags: c#, string, list

I am trying to write one of my first c# scripts for a homeautomation solution (homeseer). I have other issues to resolve with the below code, however the simple line:

```
String[] parm = line.Split(",");
```

Results in the error:

> Type 'string' does not contain a definition for `Split' and no
>   extension method 'Split' of type 'string' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I will post another question for my other issues

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public void Main(string line)
{
    String[] parm = line.Split(",");
    var windowDoorOpenVar = hs.GetVar("WindowDoorOpen");
    if (windowDoorOpenVar.Size == 0 || windowDoorOpenVar == null)
    {
        hs.CreateVar("WindowDoorOpen");
        List<string> windowDoorOpen = new List<string>();
    }
    else
    {
        List windowDoorOpen = windowDoorOpenVar;
    }

    switch (parm[0])
    {
        case "Open":
            windowDoorOpen.Add(parm[1]);
            break;
        case "Closed":
            windowDoorOpen.Remove(parm[1]);
            break;
    }
    hs.SaveVar("WindowDoorOpen", windowDoorOpen);
}
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567777/unable-to-split-strings-and-confusing-requirements

Comment: `var parms = line.Split(',');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) only has these overloads

[`Split(String[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_)

> Splits a string into a maximum number of substrings based on the
>   strings in an array. You can specify whether the substrings include
>   empty array elements.

[`Split(Char[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_)

> Splits a string into a maximum number of substrings based on the
>   characters in an array.

[`Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_)

> Splits a string into substrings based on the strings in an array. You
>   can specify whether the substrings include empty array elements

[`Split(Char[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___)

> Splits a string into substrings that are based on the characters in an
>   array.

[`Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_)

> Splits a string into substrings based on the characters in an array.
>   You can specify whether the substrings include empty array elements.

[`Split(Char[], Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_)

> Splits a string into a maximum number of substrings based on the
>   characters in an array. You also specify the maximum number of
>   substrings to return.

---

If you really don't like typing the array `new []{","}` , you could roll-your-own *Extension Method* specifically for a single `string` and alike

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static string[] Split(this string source, string value, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
   {
      return source?.Split(new[] { value }, options);
   }

   public static string[] Split(this string source, params string[] values)
   {
      return source?.Split(values, StringSplitOptions.None);
   }
}

...

// usage
var someString = "string";
someString.Split(",");
someString.Split(",",".");
someString.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Interesting engouh, the reason you can call `Split(',')` is because it uses a `params` array

[params (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

> By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that
>   takes a variable number of arguments.
>
> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified
>   in the parameter declaration or an array of arguments of the specified
>   type. You also can send no arguments. If you send no arguments, the
>   length of the params list is zero.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Only after changing the param variable to "params" specifically did my script work.

Answer (score 2):

Change like this.

```
String[] parm = line.Split(',');
```

Split works with char, not string which you expected form..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `','` instead of `","`, because when you are using double quotes it's string type, but there is no overload of the `String.Split()` that recieves string as single parameter. You can use other overloads that are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 2):

The error message might seem a little strange, but it comes down to the fact that there is no method `Split` that takes a single argument of type `string`.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2), your options are:

- [Split(String[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_)
- [Split(Char[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_)
- [Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_)
- [Split(Char[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___)
- [Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_)
- [Split(Char[], Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_)

The closest overload that takes a `string` would be written like this:

```
line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or

```
line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Alternatively, you can simply call it with a char:

```
line.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `","` with `','`

`string.Split()` does not take string parameter for the separator characters, it does take an array of chars.